# XSLT select parent node with filtered child nodes

Tags: xslt

I have following xml and i want to get "Employees" node with all child Employee node whose department is "HR". How can i do that in XSLT:

```
<Company>
  <Employees>
     <Employee>
       <Id>1</Id>
       <Department>HR</Department>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
       <Id>2</Id>
       <Department>IT</Department>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
       <Id>3</Id>
       <Department>HR</Department>
     </Employee>
  </Employees>
</Company>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. There is only one `Employees` node in your example. You can either select it - along with **all** its children - or not. -- In addition, selecting is done using XPath; XSLT is used to transform the selection. What is the result you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

This will transform your document into a similar document, but without those pesky IT employees.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <xsl:if test="Department='HR'">
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employees>
     <Employee>
       <Id>1</Id>
       <Department>HR</Department>
     </Employee>

     <Employee>
       <Id>3</Id>
       <Department>HR</Department>
     </Employee>
  </Employees>
</Company>
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on @Rob's correct answer. XPath can select nodes from the source document but it can't change them. If you select an Employees node then it will be unchanged from the original, that is, it will have all the same children. If you want an Employees element with different children from the original, then you need to do a transformation, involving selective copying: which is what this solution does.